# Using Extensions to converte image from array of bits to bitmapimage in View

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

i need to call an extension in the view and not in my constructor so that i can see an image here my image

```
 <Image Grid.Row="1"
                               Grid.Column="1"
                               Width="250"
                               Height="133"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                               Source="{Binding CitizenRegisterViewModel.CurrentDelegation.SignatureImage3.Content}" />
```

it's a array of bits

i found a converter :

```
  public static BitmapImage ToBitmapImage(this byte[] byteArrayIn)
        {

                MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
                stream.Write(byteArrayIn, 0, byteArrayIn.Length);
                stream.Position = 0;
                System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(stream);
                BitmapImage returnImage = new BitmapImage();
                returnImage.BeginInit();
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                img.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
                ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                returnImage.StreamSource = ms;
                returnImage.EndInit();

                return returnImage;


        }
```

i would like to use it in the view is it possible because i m using the currentdelegation

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39366641/1136211

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this converter

```
public class ByteToBitmapImageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        var bytes = value as byte[];
        if (bytes == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(value));

        return bytes.ToBitmapImage();
    }

    public static BitmapImage ToBitmapImage(this byte[] byteArrayIn)
    {

        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        stream.Write(byteArrayIn, 0, byteArrayIn.Length);
        stream.Position = 0;
        System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(stream);
        BitmapImage returnImage = new BitmapImage();
        returnImage.BeginInit();
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        img.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
        ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        returnImage.StreamSource = ms;
        returnImage.EndInit();

        return returnImage;


    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

and update your view.

```
<Image Grid.Row="1"
       Grid.Column="1"
       Width="250"
       Height="133"
       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
       Source="{Binding CitizenRegisterViewModel.CurrentDelegation.SignatureImage3.Content,Converter={StaticResource ByteToBitmapImageConverter}}" />
```

And add your converter to page

```
<Page.Resources>
    <converters:ByteToBitmapImageConverter x:Key="ByteToBitmapImageConverter" />
</Page.Resources>
```

Comment: That Convert method is far too complicated. See my answer for how it should actually look like.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Binding Converter like this one:

```
public class ImageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(
        object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        BitmapImage bitmap = null;
        var buffer = value as byte[];

        if (buffer != null)
        {
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream(buffer))
            {
                bitmap = BitmapFrame.Create(
                    stream, BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
            }
        }

        return bitmap;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(
        object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Create an instance of the converter as resource in XAML and set the `Converter` property of the Binding:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:ImageConverter x:Key="ImageConverter "/>
</Window.Resources>


<Image ... Source="{Binding
    CitizenRegisterViewModel.CurrentDelegation.SignatureImage3.Content
    Converter={StaticResource ImageConverter}}" />
```

---

Note also that all the above is usually unnecessary, as WPF provides built-in automatic type conversion from several source types, including `byte[]`, to `ImageSource` (the type of the `Source` property of the Image control). So your binding should already work without any converter.