# Display image from byte[ ]

Tags: c#, wpf, image, xaml, byte

I use C#, wpf. I have an image, it is stored in the form of: **byte[ ]**

```
public interface IFile
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    byte[] FileData { get; set; }        
    string FileName { get; set; }
    int? FileSize { get; set; }
    string FileExtension { get; set; }
}
```

How can I display my image (FileData **byte[ ]**) on the form?

```
<GroupBox BorderThickness="1">
    <Image Source="..."/>
</GroupBox>
```

I have to write in `Source="..."`, if I create a temporary file from a byte[ ]?

Comment: Since WPF provides built-in type conversion from several source types (including `byte[]`) to `ImageSource`, you should be able to simply write `<Image Source="{Binding FileData}"/>`. The byte array must contain an encoded image buffer, e.g. a PNG or JPEG.

Comment: For the Binding to work, the DataContext of the Image control (or one of its parent controls or the MainWindow), must be set to an instance of a class that implements your IFile interface.

Comment: Clemens, thanks! really works!!

Comment: As it was not an exact duplicate, I've reopened the question and added an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Provided that you have a view model class that implements your `IFile` interface, and that its `FileData` property contains an encoded image buffer like a PNG or JPEG, you could directly bind to the property like this:

```
<Image Source="{Binding FileData}"/>
```

This is because WPF provides built-in, automatic type conversion from several source types, including `byte[]`, to `ImageSource`.

---

The type conversion is performed by the class `ImageSourceConverter`, which is registered as TypeConverter

```
[TypeConverterAttribute(typeof(ImageSourceConverter))]
public abstract class ImageSource ...
```

and does something similar to this:

```
byte[] buffer = ...
ImageSource result;
using (var stream = new MemoryStream(buffer))
{
    result = BitmapFrame.Create(
        stream, BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
}
```